# Can the replication be on different node types?

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

I'm a newbie to Kubernetes, but I'm confused about one thing:

Let's say I've set a pod's replication to 100.

Is it possible to assign a portion of that 100, eg 80, to one node-type, specfically PREEMPTIBLE nodes, and the remaining 20 to another node-type, eg NON-preemtimble nodes?

If that's NOT possible, then is the "correct" way to achieve this is to have 2 pods and each one is set to a different node type? But then, can the containers within the pods from one node type (eg PREemptible nodes) still communicate *just as easily* (ie just by using hostname?) with the containers on other pods on the other node type (eg NON-preemtible nodes)?

Answer (score 2):

You can setup Node Affinity on the pods.This will help distribute the pods between the nodes. It might not distribute exactly 80/20 (using the example given); however, the Scheduler will take into consideration the weight of the nodes. In this case, the node types do not matter. You can read more about Node Affinity [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/#affinity-and-anti-affinity).